# Plotting polygon shapefile with ggplot2 jumbles up the polygons

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile

I have a polygon shape file with village polygons for two different districts. When I plot this using base package

```
plot(shp_test,axes=T)
```

I get the following figure:
[image]

However, when I try to plot this using ggplot2,

```
shp_fort<-fortify(shp_test)
ggplot() + geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat), data=shp_fort, fill="red", alpha=.5)
```

I observe the following result.
[image]

Could someone please explain what is happening here and how to resolve this.

***I have not shared the shapefile here as its a big data set. However if still required please post a comment and I shall share the shapefile too.***

Comment: Try: `ggplot() + geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat, group = id), data=shp_fort, fill="red", alpha=.5)`

Comment: @johannes: Many thanks! It worked. I see now that group was the important aesthetic missing.

Comment: @johannes turned your comment into an answer, as it seems it worked for OP and so its preserved for future reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by johannes [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51942926/plotting-polygon-shapefile-with-ggplot2-jumbles-up-the-polygons#comment90835620_51942926), you should use the `group` aesthetic and pass it the `id` of your element:

```
ggplot() + geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=id), data=shp_fort, fill="red", alpha=.5)
```

In [this example](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_polygon.html#examples) from the ggplot2 page, they indicate the need to use such `id` when using `geom_polygon` (emphasis mine):

> # When using geom_polygon, you will typically need two data frames: 
>   # one contains the coordinates of each polygon (positions),  and the 
>   # other the values associated with each polygon (values).  **An id 
>
>   # variable links the two together**